# How to get value of input type number

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, input

I'm making a mobile app with cordova. therefore my code needs to be compatible with android and ios browsers

I need to restrict the length of my input to 3 digits which works however is I enter any non-digit characters this doesn't work.

Here's my input

```
 <input id="age" type="number">
```

Here's my js

```
$("#age").bind("keyup", function (e) {
            var ageSelector = $('#age');

            if (ageSelector.val().length > 3) {
                ageSelector.val(ageSelector.val().substr(0, 3));
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSdj8/

How can I get the real value in the input? or better how can I prevent the user from inputting all non-digit characters?

Comment: What's that fiddle? You sure you posted the right one?

Comment: sorry, just changed it

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) which will return true if it's not a number, you can use `maxlength` attribute also

```
<input id="age" type="number" maxlength="3">

$("#age").bind("keyup", function (e) {
    var ageSelector = $('#age');
    var val=ageSelector.val();
    if(isNaN(parseInt(val)))
        ageSelector.val(val.substr(0, val.length-1));
    if (val.length > 3) {
        ageSelector.val(val.substr(0, 3));
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/DyBy7/5/)

Comment: Because I have to set the type to number (to prompt the correct keyboard on iOS and Android) the value of the input is not what is actually displayed.
The fiddle that you posted doesn't work, I can still input more than 3 characters (if they're not numbers)

Comment: You probably have to replace  `if(isNaN(val))` with `if(isNaN(parseInt(val)))` (isNaN is working strange on strings..) And even that isn't perfect

Comment: that works better, however I'm trying to limit the length of the input to 3 characters (number or otherwise) rather than empty the input if the user doesn't enter a number

Comment: sadly the client is really strict, I may have found a solution, I'll post it if it works, thanks for trying to help though I really appreciate it.